# How to use regular expression in snowflake?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Rule: 
1. Start with R ;
2. One or more number ;
3. One space ;
4. Follow with other characters ;

Test case:
Input         :  'R1 ABC' 'R4 DEF' 'Randwick Acca' 'R11 PPP'

Expect Output :  'R1 ABC' 'R4 DEF' 'R11 PPP'

Regular expression : "R\d{1,} " 
I use regular expression tester, it works. 
https://regex-golang.appspot.com/assets/html/index.html?_sm_au_=iHVPMjQb0QjFkMTHfLJ4vK7214sJW

Test query:

```
WITH tbl 
AS (select t.column1 mycol from values('R1 ABC'),('R4 DEF'),('Randwick Acca'),('R11 PPP') t)
SELECT *
FROM tbl 
WHERE mycol regexp 'R\d{1,} ' ;
```

Return NULL .

Thanks,
Bin

Answer (score 1):

1) where's the "any other character"? Because what you have ends with space, period

2) welcome to SQL. \ is a special character and needs to be escaped

So:

```
WHERE mycol regexp 'R\\d{1,} .*';
```

I tested it on your query and it seemed to work

Comment: there's also a shorthand for `{1,}` which is `+`, So `R\\d+ .*` also works